# A metric space in which no non-empty countable subset has empty interior.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

A Question: Find a metric space in which no non-empty countable subset has empty interior.

My Answer: In a discrete metric space $X$, $int(S) = S$ for all $S ⊂ X$. And if $S$ is non-empty (and countable) then so is $int(S)$.

Now I want to ask.....is there any other example of such a metric space??

Comment: Do you mean countably infinite, or at most countably infinite when you say countable?

Answer (score 1):

If countable is meant to include finite sets, then every metric space (or any space) with this property is discrete, because one point sets are open. If however "countable" only means countably infinite, there are other examples. For example, consider the space
$$\{1/n|n\in \mathbb N\}\cup \{0\}$$
The one point set $\{0\}$ is not open, but every other one point set is. Thus a countably infinite set contains at least one open point, hence has nonempty interior. This can of course be generalized to a space with only finitely many points that are not open.

Comment: Countable *could* mean finite or countable.

Comment: @AsafKaragila that's usually what I use it to mean, but it seemed too boring.

Comment: Tough cookie! :-P